# Sum of representations and characters of the symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Hi I was wondering if I could have some help to go in the right direction.

I want to show that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_n} (sgn(\sigma)*\chi(\sigma)) =0$

where $sgn(\sigma)$ : $S_n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the representation which is 1 is $\sigma$ is even and -1 if odd and $\chi(\sigma)$ is the character of an irreducible representation of $S_n$.

So I know that the inner product of a character of an irreducible representation with itself is 1, do I have to do something along these lines? But since we are over $S_n$ and not any particular symmetric group how do we know how many even or odd permutations there are in order for us to get zero?

any help is appreciated, I am struggling a bit with this subject.

thanks

Comment: Note that you need to assume that $\chi$ is not the sign character here, or it is clearly false.

Comment: yes, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parity of an element $sgn(\sigma)$ gives you a linear (irreducible) *character* (one-dimensional representation). Hence, by Frobenius orthogonality relations, the inner product with the other characters is $0$, and this is exactly your sum! (Note that conjugate permutations have the same sign)

Comment: Thank you very much, makes a lot more sense now !